# Azure web role - Disable Tls 1.0

Tags: azure, ssl

Is Microsoft supporting "Disabling TLS l.0 on Exchange server"? If I enable TLS 1.0 then everything works fine. If I disable TLS 1.0 then it is saying

> server socket exception.

By my PCI scan results to disable TLS 1.0.

So, please help me to disable TLS 1.0.